# How do I handle errors in Lua when executing arbitrary strings?

Tags: c++11, lua, lua-api

I'm going for absolute minimalism here. (It's been a while since I've worked with the Lua C API.)

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    lua_State* state = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(state);

    string input;

    while (getline(cin, input))
    {
        auto error = luaL_dostring(state, input.c_str());

        if (error)
        {
            cerr << "Lua Error: " << lua_tostring(state, -1) << '\n';
            lua_pop(state, 1);
        }
    }

    lua_close(state);
    return 0;
}
```

This program works fine as long as I feed it perfect Lua. However, if I enter something bad (such as `asdf()`), the program crashes! Why is it not handling my error gracefully?

I've tried breaking out the calls before. It crashes on the call to `lua_pcall` itself. I never make it past that line.

Comment: Have you checked `stderr`?

Comment: Your program works fine for me. (I had to change `auto` to `int`, though.)

Comment: I have the same results as @lhf. What compiler are you using? What does "crashes" mean here exactly? What operating system is this?

Comment: Wellllll.... it seems I was just unlucky. See my answer below. :(

Comment: @EtanReisner, it was essentially a Windows seg fault. "This program has stopped working." It literally just exits the program the instant it reaches `lua_pcall`. You should be able to reproduce my results if you download the 5.2.1 x64 static library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary download (5.2.1 I believe) has a bug that was corrected in 5.2.3. I rebuilt the library from source, and now my program works fine.